How much is this coin in "Mad Men" worth?
From the TV show, Mad Men, season 1, episode 8, "The Hobo Code," a homeless person visits young Dick's family ranch and is offered a meal and work.
Over the dinner table, Dick's stepmom takes a coin out of a jar and offers it to the homeless person.
I have searched on Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coins_of_the_United_States_dollar, but could not find it.
I am wondering what kind of coin it is and how much it is worth at that time (Great Depression era).


That's a 1920 "Standing Liberty" quarter (25¢)

In the 1930s it would buy you a couple of loaves of bread or a dozen eggs.


interesting, I am wondering why it is not listed in the Wikipedia page for American coins

It's certainly on Wikipedia; https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_Liberty_quarter

@YuZhang - Because you need to go and add it to the Wikipedia article on American coins?

@YuZhang it's mentioned on the page for coinage type set https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_coinage_type_set and on quarter mintage figures https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_quarter_mintage_figures

@YuZhang.  It's not listed on the page you originally linked to because its no longer in circulation and it is a collector's or investors item.  The Standing Liberty Quarter was 90% silver, as such, even if it were extremely damaged it would now be worth about $5.50 for the silver content.  In good or better condition, the value for 1920 liberty quarter  can range from $15 to >$200, depending on the condition and which mint mark it has.

@RisingZan - That explains why I've never seen one in circulation in my half century + living in the USA.

@T.E.D  My late father-in-law was a coin collector, and I spent quite a bit of time this summer going through his collection and making a rough inventory and value estimate so I got very familiar with recognizing the silver coins. All dimes, quarters, half-dollars and dollar coins pre-1965 are 90% silver.  Half-dollars from 65-70 are 40% silver.  Nickels from 43-45 (and some of 42, depending on the mint) were 35% silver, to conserve nickel for the war effort.

@RisingZan - I used to collect pennies, but it was a pretty easy hobby. Just go to the bank with $10 and ask for it changed to pennies.  Back in the 70's at least it was pretty easy to get old wheat pennies that way.
